# Sort multidimensional array by second-level key

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(3) { 
    ["Fall Quarter 2012"]=> array(2) { 
          [20121018]=> array(1) { 
              ["agenda"]=> string(55) "Fall_2012/Agenda_20121018.pdf" 
          }
          [20121011]=> array(2) { 
              ["agenda"]=> string(55) "Fall_2012/Agenda_20121011.pdf" 
              ["minutes"]=> string(56) "Fall_2012/Minutes_20121011.pdf" 
          } 
    } 
    ["Spring Quarter 2012"]=> array(1) { 
          [20120413]=> array(1) { 
              ["agenda"]=> string(57) "SPRing_2012/Agenda_20120413.pdf" 
          } 
    } 
    ["Summer Quarter 2012"]=> array(1) { 
          [20120610]=> array(2) { 
              ["agenda"]=> string(57) "Summer_2012/Agenda_20120610.pdf" 
              ["minutes"]=> string(58) "Summer_2012/Minutes_20120610.pdf" 
          } 
    } 
 }
```

And I'd like to sort it using date keys so that quarters are in the right order Fall/Summer/Spring. Which should look like this:

```
array(3) { 
    ["Fall Quarter 2012"]=> array(2) {
          [20121018]=> array(1) { 
              ["agenda"]=> string(55) "Fall_2012/Agenda_20121018.pdf" 
          }
          [20121011]=> array(2) { 
              ["agenda"]=> string(55) "Fall_2012/Agenda_20121011.pdf" 
              ["minutes"]=> string(56) "Fall_2012/Minutes_20121011.pdf" 
          } 
    }
    ["Summer Quarter 2012"]=> array(1) { 
          [20120610]=> array(2) { 
              ["agenda"]=> string(57) "Summer_2012/Agenda_20120610.pdf" 
              ["minutes"]=> string(58) "Summer_2012/Minutes_20120610.pdf" 
          } 
    } 
    ["Spring Quarter 2012"]=> array(1) { 
          [20120413]=> array(1) { 
              ["agenda"]=> string(57) "SPRing_2012/Agenda_20120413.pdf" 
          } 
    } 
 }
```

Is there a way to get this result by sorting using date, or should I use [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) function to sort quarters with my own pattern?

Please, let me know what you think! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the uasort function. Your code could look something like this:

```
function myComparison($a, $b){
    return (key($a) > key($b)) ? -1 : 1;
} 

uasort ( $quarters , 'myComparison' );
```

That will sort using `$quarters["Fall Quarter 2012"]["20121018"]` for example

Comment: Thanks! This sorts fine but how do I keep quarters' names? When I sort like this it turns my keys (Fall Quarter 2012/Summer Quarter 2012/ Spring Quarter 2012) into (0/1/2). Also it should be ">" and not "<".

Comment: And also changed the `<` to a `>` in the comparison function