# Array sort in alphabetical order (Quicker Way)

Tags: php

Hey guys i didn't found my answer in internet.
Really simple question : How can i order an "complex" array in alphabetical order (the quicker way)

Exemple of an array :

```
array = [
    "0": [
             "username": "B_User1",
             "age": "134",
             "size": "4m13",
         ],
    "1": [
             "username": "A_User2",
             "age": "134",
             "size": "4m13",
         ],
    "2": [
             "username": "I_User3",
             "age": "134",
             "size": "4m13",
         ],
    "3": [
             "username": "R_User4",
             "age": "134",
             "size": "4m13",
         ],
    "4": [
             "username": "Z_User5",
             "age": "134",
             "size": "4m13",
         ],
    "6": [
             "username": "Q_User6",
             "age": "134",
             "size": "4m13",
         ],
];
```

And i want to sort this array in alphabetical order for username.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865167/sort-multidimensional-array-by-second-level-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this function with PHP 5.3

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['username'] - $b['username'];
});
```

or use **[array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)**

```
 $keys = array_column($myArray, 'username');
 $result = array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $myArray);
```

And, with **PHP 7** you can use the spaceship operator:

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['username'] <=> $b['username'];
});
```

Comment: you could use the spaceship operator ;)

Comment: Spaceship (or strcmp if it's not available) would definitely be the way to go. Doing it with subtraction is just going to raise a lot of warnings about non-numeric values instead of sorting anything.

Comment: I have this ... Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Comment: I tryied first version

Comment: Ok Solve for me (first one) : return $a->['username'] > $b->['username'];